I am getting error TS7053 (screenshot inside) because the type is not correct
I'm using react-hook-form, so after submit I get the data as an object that has a FileList with the file from the form at index "0".
For some reason when uploading the file to firebase, it gives an error and I don't quite understand its meaning:
TS7053: Element implicitly has any type because expression of type 0 can't be used to index type string | File
type RecipeUpload = {
  title: string,
  descr: string,
  by: string,
  image: File | string
}

uploadBytes(img, e.image[0]).then(data => {
    getDownloadURL(data.ref).then(val => {
      e.image = val
      console.log(e, val)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })

Complaints about the string e.image[0]

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

If e is an instance of RecipeUpload then e.image is of type File | string, which indeed is not an array.  Are you expecting an array?  Why?

@KenWhite But everything on the screenshot I copied here (I cut out unnecessary moments).

@Dunker - Again, why are you using [0] on e.image? If it's a File, that's just incorrect, and if it's a string, that will give you one code unit (loosely, character) from the string, neither of which seems like what you want to do...? If you were trying to access a code unit in the string, you'd have to narrow e.image first by checking that it is a string (there are lots of answered questions on that), but...

If you copied everything on the screenshot and put it in as text, then you don't need the image at all. Right? Please do NOT post images unless there is absolutely no other way to demonstrate a problem, such as when something graphical isn't rendering properly. Read the link I provided to see why images should be avoided as much as  posslble.

The image property of RecipeUpload is defined to be either a File or a string.  It's not an array, and it doesn't make sense to index it with [0].  That's what the message is trying to tell you.  Have you considered just removing the [0] since it doesn't make sense?
